# Laravel deserialise message

Tags: c#, laravel

In my c# application I receive the following message from an external device.

```
Title: Color, Text: 6, Number: 0, Logic: false
```

How can I make properties from this string message?

Normally I deserialize it but in this case it's no json!

Comment: Deserialization is the generic name for the process of parsing *something* and returning classes. There is no one generic deserializer. There are binary, xml and json deserializers among others. If you want to deserialize a custom format, you'll have to create the deserializer yourself. What *is* this format? Perhaps someone has already created a deserializer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can always fall back to good old manual parsing... Assuming the property values will never contain the character `,`, you can do something like this:

```
static IDictionary<string, string> Parse(string input)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var pairs = input.Split(',');
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        var parts = pair.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);
        string name = parts[0];
        string value = parts[1];
        result.Add(name, value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

(of course, if you want to deserialize it as an object you'll have to convert each value to the actual property type)